# How to track total time using for any app?

Tags: applications, tasker

To track time on Android, I use Time Meter, which supports Tasker. But in the configuration screen of Time Meter plugin in Tasker, I don't know how to put the foreground app name to it. Do you know how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many apps that can track time usage: ManicTime, RescueTime, SmarterTime

Answer (score 1):

Variables can be used in those fields. The variable for the running app is [`%WIN`](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/variables.html). You can create a profile to check if the name has been assigned to the variable:

```
Profile > Event > Variable Set: %WIN

LINK TO TASK:
A1. Flash %WIN
```

[image]